# How to update table row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a table that displays items selected by the user. Right now, when the user adds an item, the item is added as a new row. I tried changing it so that instead of creating a new row it increments an amount. This, however, didn't work as I got an error saying I need an else after the `:`.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {this.state.basket.map(item => {
      return (
        {this.getAmount(item) === 0 ? (
          <tr>
            <td>{item}</td>
            <td>{this.getAmount(item)}</td>
          </tr>
        ) : (
          this.updateAmount(item);
        )
      )
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How would I change this to have an `amount` next to the item?

Get amount method:

```
getAmount = item => {
  var amount = 0;
  var basket = [...this.state.basket];
  basket.forEach(i => {
    if (i === item) {
      amount++;
    }
  });
  console.log(item + " : " + amount);
  return parseInt(amount);
};
```

Update amount method:

```
updateAmount = item => {
  return this.getAmount(item);
};
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the `updateAmount` function ?

Comment: @ArnaudChrist I did :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to increment the amount for the item in state if it is 0? What does `getAmount` do?

Comment: Then maybe also the `getAmount` function :) And I don't know if it is a typo when in your code you have `this.get.getAmount(item)` ? If not, what is `this.get` ?

Comment: I assume the part in the "else" should have some form of JSX, but not too sure what to put.

Comment: Why not calling directly `this.getAmount(item)` instead of `updateAmount` (which is then quite misleading) ?

Comment: Don't do this. When you click add, just increment the size within that function, then just render the row normally.

Comment: @lux So if I am understanding correctly, I should implement the getAmount method into the addToBasket method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS state vs prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481061/reactjs-state-vs-prop)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to React but it looks like the method you're calling in your 'else' is just returning some value and not jsx. Your 'if' result is returning jsx but your else is just calling a function that just returns a value.

```
getAmount = item => {
  var amount = 0;
  var basket = [...this.state.basket];
  basket.forEach(i => {
    if (i === item) {
      amount++;
    }
  });
  console.log(item + " : " + amount);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <span>{parseInt(amount)}</span>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
};
```

I am more than likely way off since I just started learning React but I figure it's worth a shot if it does help. Or you may be able to do the `<React.Fragment>` part right in your else and put the function inside of a `<span>` but not sure if that would work.

Comment: sorry about that...could also try taking the map out of the table and creating a separate renderCount method for it, then in the renderCount method debug along the way. when you hit that else console.log(parseInt(amount)) and see what you get and work from there? I had an issue like this and it had to do with what I was actually returning from the map.